# Obtener cambios del valor de una variable en php en JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Quiero pasar un valor que se da en una variable `$_SESSION['T']` de **PHP** a **JQuery**. Esta variable va cambiando su valor a medida que se presiona en los inputs de tipo "button" que tengo en **HTML5**. 
Para el input *"Anterior"* la variable va en decremento (-) y claro para el input *"Siguiente"* la variable se va incrementando (+). Esto anda perfecto.

Ahora lo que quiero es que cuando llegue al primer registro (se logra al ir haciendo clic en el input *"Anterior"*) ese mismo botón quede deshabilitado y si llega al final (clic en el input *"Siguiente"*) lo mismo.

El problema es que no puedo lograr esto desde **JQuery**, si bien el valor lo puedo ver desde la consola (por ejemplo, el registro 21 que es con el que arranca) cuando apreto en los botones *"Anterior"* o *"Siguiente"* esa variable **T** que está en *PHP* (en JQuery es nombrada como **Nro**) no cambia. Por ende parece que está siempre en el mismo registro (21), cuando debería cambiar al número 20 (para el *"Anterior"*) o 22 (para el *"Siguiente"*).

Este es una parte del código que tengo de **PHP**:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['T'])) {
    $_SESSION['T']=21;
}else{
    if(isset($_POST['Ant']) && !empty($_POST['Ant'])) {
         $_SESSION['T']--;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['Sig']) && !empty($_POST['Sig'])) {
         $_SESSION['T']++;
    }
}
   $T=$_SESSION['T'];
```

Y el código que tengo para ambos botones desde **JQuery** es:

```
$('body').on('click', '#Ant, #Sig', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $btn = $(e.target);
    $(".Tips").hide();
    $("#carga").show();
    var dataString = $('#FrmBus').serialize() + '&' + 
    encodeURI($btn.attr('name')) + '=' + encodeURI($btn.val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:81/prueba/",type: "POST",
        data:dataString,
        cache:false,
        success:function(data)
        {
             $("#carga").hide();
             $(".Tips").show();
             var $response=$.parseHTML(data);
             $response=$('.Tips',$response).html();
             $(".Tips").html($response);
             $("input:button").button();
            //$btn.prop('disabled', false);
            var Nro = <?php echo $T?>;
            if (Nro==1){
                $("#Ant").prop('disabled',true);
            }else if (Nro==1){
                $("#Sig").prop('disabled',true);
            }else{
                console.log("El registro actual es el "+ Nro);
            }
        }});
       return false;
});
```

Quizás no se puede manipular de esa forma, hablo de la línea `var Nro = <?php echo $T?>;` también he probado con `json_encode ()` y tampoco me da resultado. ¿Será un problema de los valores del lado del servidor?

Comment: No sera que a <?php echo $T?>; le falta un `;` <?php echo __$T;__?>

Comment: Ese estilo de programación da pie a código espagueti, recomiendo dejar todo lo que se ejecuta del lado del servidor en el servidor y lo que se ejecuta del lado del cliente en el cliente.

Comment: No ese ; (punto y como) no es. Ya lo probe y es lo mismo.

Comment: El código `var Nro = <?php echo $T?>;`  no funcionará, siempre tendrá el valor inicial, pues PHP solo se ejecuta una vez, cuando se genera la página, aunque el javascript se ejecute muchas veces ¿comprendes? la pagina **nunca** se refresca, por lo tanto el valor nunca cambia.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer, es mandar el valor en los parámetros del ajax y traerlo de vuelta en su respuesta (en la variable  data)

Comment: Solo tienes que devolver en tu ajax del lado del servidor el nuevo valor de esa variable de sesión y en el success de tu ajax actualizar el value del botón ya que eso e slo que vas mandando para que incremente o decremente

Comment: Entiendo. Voy a buscar más info sobre este tema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione agregando en **PHP** un `input type='hidden'` siempre dentro del formulario, quedando:

```
echo "<form id='FrmBus' method='post' action=''>";
echo "<input type='hidden' id='Cant' value='".$_SESSION['T']."'>";
echo "<p style='text-align:center'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' name='Ant' id='Ant' value='<<' title='Ver anterior publicación'><input type='button' name='Sig' id='Sig' value='>>' title='Ver Siguiente publicación'></p></form>";
```

Y luego la parte de la llamada en **JQuery** me queda:

```
...
var Nro = $("#Cant").val();
if (Nro==1){
    $("#Ant").hide();
}else if (Nro==22){
    $("#Sig").hide();
}
...
```

Quizás le sirva a otra persona.